# Extracting the file extensions from file names in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column `FileName` in pandas dataframe which consists of strings containing filenames of the form . The filename can contain dots('.') in them. For example, a `a.b.c.d.txt` is a txt file. I just want to have another column `FileType` column containing only the file extensions.

Sample DataFrame:

```
FileName

a.b.c.d.txt

j.k.l.exe
```

After processing:

```
FileName    FileType

a.b.c.d.txt txt

j.k.l.exe   exe
```

I tried the following:

```
X['FileType'] = X.FileName.str.split(pat='.')
```

This help me split the string on `.`. But how do I get the last element i.e. the file extension?

Something like

```
X['FileType'] = X.FileName.str.split(pat='.')[-1]

X['FileType'] = X.FileName.str.split(pat='.').pop(-1)
```

did not give the desired output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Option 1***
 **`apply`**

```
df['FileType'] = df.FileName.apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
```

***Option 2***
Use **`str`** twice

```
df['FileType'] = df.FileName.str.split('.').str[-1]
```

***Option 2b***
Use **`rsplit`** (thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ)

```
df['FileType'] = df.FileName.str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]
```

All result in:

```
      FileName FileType
0  a.b.c.d.txt      txt
1    j.k.l.exe      exe
```

---

<sub>`Python 3.6.4, Pandas 0.22.0`</sub>

Comment: As a slight improvement to your solution, I would recommend a simple `rsplit`—`df.FileName.str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]`... this splits only once from the right, so should be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you *don't* want to split the extension from the filename, then I would recommend a list comprehension—

## comprehension with `str.rsplit`

```
df['FileType'] = [f.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] for f in df.FileName.tolist()]
df

      FileName FileType
0  a.b.c.d.txt      txt
1    j.k.l.exe      exe
```

---

If you want to split the path and the filename, there are a couple of options.

## `os.path.splitext`

```
import os

pd.DataFrame(
    [os.path.splitext(f) for f in df.FileName], 
    columns=['Name', 'Type']
)
 
      Name  Type
0  a.b.c.d  .txt
1    j.k.l  .exe
```

---

## `str.extract`

```
df.FileName.str.extract(r'(?P<FileName>.*)(?P<FileType>\..*)', expand=True)

      Name  Type
0  a.b.c.d  .txt
1    j.k.l  .exe
```